# How to invoke iteration API query in Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to invoke the Rest API below for getting list of work items which are mapping to a specific iteration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/get%20iteration%20work%20items?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Ultimately I want to invoke this as part of the Approval step in my Release pipeline so that the approver can verify if all work items for a given iteration are in Completed state.

I have two questions:

1. I don't know how to get the values for {team} and {iterationid}
2. How do I invoke this API as part of the approval gate. Should I use a Generic service connection? What user name and password do I need to provide?

Any working example here will be really helpful.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get teams, you can use [Teams - Get Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get%20teams?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) on Team Project.
2. Then you can find all team iterations and their ids [Iterations - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
3. You can use gates with azure function. Here is the example: [Azure DevOps release gates with Azure Functions, PowerShell and VS Code](https://medium.com/@shayki5/azure-devops-release-gates-with-azure-functions-powershell-and-vs-code-cd98a920887f)

Additionally, you may consider to use quality gates with a work item query: [Use approvals and gates to control your deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops)